# Copy files from local to Hadoop automatically

Tags: linux, hadoop, cron, hdfs

I want to copy updated files from local file system to Hadoop every hour as i want to put in cron. Is there any hadoop command that i can use to copy the updated files from local to Hadoop?

Comment: In the most simple case, you can make a shellscript to remove the old file and put the new one using hadoop fs -rm fileName and hadoop fs -put sourceFile destinationPath

Comment: "is there any hadoop command" - yes, it's the one you'd use to manually copy files. Have you tried writing the cron job?

Comment: Thank you, but how can we know if the files are updated or how frequently do we need run the command you mentioned above to copy the latest files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use various data ingestion tools like Flume,Nifi etc.

Please let me know if you need any help on these tools.

Comment: Hi Kushagra, Please share your details so that i can learn those tools.

Answer (score 0):

Something like below code?
In folder with your files

```
files=$(find . -type f -mmin -60)

for f in $files
do
  hadoop fs -cp $f /hadoopdest
done
```

Maybe another loop for created files:

```
files_c=$( find . -type f -cmin -60)
```